# Show connection of gradient and level curve for function $f(x,y)=2x^2-y^2$ at point A(2,3)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

As title is saying I need to show connection of gradient and level curve for function

$f(x,y)=2x^2-y^2$

at point

$A(2,3)$.

First I find gradient of function:

$\nabla f(x,y) = 4x-2y $

At point A:

$\nabla f(2,3) = (8,-6)$

Then for $f(x,y) = f(2,3)$:

$2x^2-y^2=-1$

We see that this equation of hyperbola. So I am having problem with parameterization of this equation.
Because this is vertical hyperbola:

$
x=b \tan(t)
$

$
y=a \sec(t)
$

I have tried to do it this way.
Vector $\vec{r}$ is equal to:

$
\vec{r} = (x(t), y(t)) = (\sqrt{2} \tan(t), \sec(t))
$

So how to get tangent vector from r?
Is this right way?

$
\vec{r}'(t) = (\sqrt{2}sec^2(t), sec(t)tan(t))
$

We know that $\vec{r}(t) = (2,3)$

$
(\sqrt{2} \tan(t), \sec(t)) = (2,3)
$

So we get $\tan(t) = \sqrt{2} $ and $\sec(t) = 3$

Then
$
\vec{r}'(t) = (9\sqrt{2}, 3\sqrt{2})
$

As theorem states:

$
\nabla f(2,3) * \vec{r}'(t) = 0
$

But I get:

$
\nabla f(2,3) * \vec{r}'(t) = (8,-6)(9\sqrt{2}, 3\sqrt{2}) = 54\sqrt{2} \neq 0
$

Comment: Your parametrization is wrong. it should be $x(t) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan t$

Comment: @dezdichado I strongly suggest you add your comment as an answer, since it does give $\nabla f(2,3)\cdot \vec{r}'(t)=0$ as required.

Comment: The function $(x,y)\mapsto A(x,y)$ has not been defined. So, what is $A(2,3)$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter $A$ is the name of the point. A few lines down, the question says, “At point A...”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making my comment an answer, so this question no longer counts as unanswered.

Your parametrization is wrong, it should be: $$\vec{r}(t) = \Big(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan t,\, \sec t\Big)$$